# Sharepoint 2013, File Upload Custom Page Lay Out

Tags: sharepoint, layout

I'm customizing a Custom Page Lay out for SP 2013 Online, but i need to upload file to Documents Folder, but i'm getting crazy, do you know any Tutorial or example?

I've tryed this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx#RunTheExamples

but returns error...

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Adding this to the Custom PAge Layout.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="openInDialog(500,600,true,true,false,'https://harepoint.com/sites/site/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%7BFBD05330-969D-4853-B00A-6E728BA87F0B%7D');" class="ms-cui-ctl-large "><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer"><span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float"><img unselectable="on" src="/_layouts/15/3082/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=38" alt="" style="top: -239px; left: -35px;"></span></span><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Cargar<br>archivo</span></a>
```

With This JS:

```
    function openInDialog(dlgWidth, dlgHeight, dlgAllowMaximize,dlgShowClose,needCallbackFunction, pageUrl, opcion) 
{    
    //cojo las opciones que le paso desde el href .
    var options = { url: pageUrl,showClose: dlgShowClose};

    if(needCallbackFunction)
    {
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseDialogCallback);
    }
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}

function CloseDialogCallback(dialogResult, returnValue)
{
    if(dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
    {  
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage', SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);          
    }
    else if(dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel)
    {   
    }else{
    }
}
```

**The Code is not Refactorized!**